# Jest test functions that define variables in it

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, mjs

I want to write some Jest tests for JavaScript functions in a .mjs file. Within these functions, variables are defined by calling other functions. For example:

```
export function getCurrentVideo() {
     var currentVideo = VideoList.GetCurrentVideo()
    console.log(currentVideo);
    return "This is the video:" + currentVideo
}
```

In this case I will receive undefined, right? Because VideoList.GetCurrentVideo can't be reached.

Test will be something like:

```
const  getCurrentVideo  = import('../').getCurrentVideo;

describe('getCurrentVideo', () => {
    test('if getCurrentVideo will return "This is the video:" + currentVideo', () => {
        expect(getCurrentVideo).toBe('This is the video:" + currentVideo');
    });
});
```

I know you can add parameters to the function, but that will mean that I have to re-write the functions just for test purposes. It isn't my code, it's a huge project where the owner wants some tests for it.

Comment: Post `VideoList` context

Comment: @AdamAzad VideoList will refer to this : 

```
export var VideoList=new VideoList("https://.....json");
```
Just a json file

Answer (score 0):

You can mock function, assuming they work correctly (and test them separately):

```
const  getCurrentVideo  = import('../').getCurrentVideo;
describe('getCurrentVideo', () => {
    it('if getCurrentVideo will return "This is the video:" + currentVideo', () => {
        const currentVideo = 'testCurrentVideo';
        window.VideoList = {
            GetCurrentVideo: jest.fn(() => currentVideo)
        }
        expect(getCurrentVideo).toBe('This is the video:' + currentVideo);
    });
});
```

Or you can provide a full context of VideoList, so that the two function are tested together.

Comment: But if I provide a full context of the VideoList, I have to re-write the function ? The function atm is without parameters 

I tried your solution to mock it, but still: undefined. Because it will still try to define the variable in the real function, if I'm correct.

Comment: in your test implementation, is `currentVideo` defined? The `jest.fn` will mock the function based on the name, so the real function won't be executed, but instead the provided one

Comment: Yeah it is. I did make a string of it. Instead of => currentVideo, I used: => 'currentVideo'. That should work, if I'm correct. If I use your example and define currentVideo, it will gave me the same output, undefined.

Comment: I think this should work, I don't see why not. But there is another problem at the moment. The import is not working (and that's maybe why your code isn't working). 

The function I want to test is inside a .mjs file. The error that I get is: Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

Comment: `import { sum }  from '../../directoryname/sum.mjs';` But even after changing it to a .js file, I got the same error. `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: i just notice, should be `it` and not `test`